# Unexpected preg_match result from pattern with "?:"

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I try this pattern

```
(?:(\d+)\/|)reports\/(\d+)-([\w-]+).html
```

with this string (preg_match with modifiers "Axu")

```
reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html
```

and i expected this matched result (https://regex101.com/r/kX6yZ5/1):

```
[1] => 683868
[2] => derger-gergewrger
```

But i get this:

```
[1] => 
[2] => 683868
[3] => derger-gergewrger
```

Why? Where does the empty value (1), because the pattern should not capture "?:"

---

I have two cases:

1. "reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html"
2. "757/reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html"

at first case, i need two captures, but at second case i need three captures.

Comment: If the captured number is not present in the string but it's presence is optional, the corresponding capture group will contain an empty string. That's by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
preg_match('~(?:\d+/)?reports/(\d+)-([\w-]+)\.html~', 
           'reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html', $m);
print_r($m);
Array
(
    [0] => reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html
    [1] => 683868
    [2] => derger-gergewrger
)
```

---

**EDIT:** You probably want this behavior:

```
$s = '757/reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html';
preg_match('~(?|(\d+)/reports/(\d+)-([\w-]+)\.html|reports/(\d+)-([\w-]+)\.html)~',
           $s, $m); print_r($m);Array
(
    [0] => 757/reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html
    [1] => 757
    [2] => 683868
    [3] => derger-gergewrger
)
```

and:

```
$s = 'reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html';

preg_match('~(?|(\d+)/reports/(\d+)-([\w-]+)\.html|reports/(\d+)-([\w-]+)\.html)~',
             $s, $m); print_r($m);
Array
(
    [0] => reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html
    [1] => 683868
    [2] => derger-gergewrger
)
```

`(?|..)` is a **Non-capturing group**. Subpatterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't, because i need capture (\d+) if it is present. I have two cases: "reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html" and "757/reports/683868-derger-gergewrger.html" and second case i need 757 too. :(

Comment: Did you forget to write about those 2 cases in question?

Comment: Yes, sorry. And i no idea, why don't working my pattern? It is must work.

Comment: Well if that part is optional then it is always better to get first captured group either a number or blank when optional part isn't there.

Comment: Yes, i think about you variant, but it sems too ugly... Ok, thank you very mutch! And for you explanation about (?|..)

Comment: Yes that's the reason my preference is also for original solution.